# conference call iOS/android?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, twilio

I have no suitable answer from twilio support so here I'm.

> At this point we're using in our app the voip product (one to one) but we need one to many.

I would like to know if it's possible to have a conference call on mobile device (iOS/android) with the twilio conference product and is it possible to use it with the twilio client or does we must do some http requests to the server by ourself ?

Or any clue ?

as requested here the code use for the 1 - 1 (iOS only, android wasn't done by me)
Here I get the token.

```
+ (BOOL)getTwilioToken{

    if(![self isCapabilityTokenValid]){
        if([APP_DELEGATE currentUser].firstName && [APP_DELEGATE currentUser].lastName){
            NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[APP_DELEGATE currentUser].firstName,[APP_DELEGATE currentUser].lastName];
            NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",TWILIO_BASE_URL,TWILIO_TOKEN_URL, fullName];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSString *token = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"capabilityToken"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here the following code use to handle the voip

```
- (void)setTwilioToken{

    NSString* token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"capabilityToken"];

    if(token){
        self.phone = [[TCDevice alloc] initWithCapabilityToken:token delegate:self];
    }

}

-(IBAction)callPressed:(id)sender{

    //[self callResponder:sender];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    //responder full name for twilio, client is required for twilio
    NSString *responderFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client:%@%@",[[self.responders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] firstName],[[self.responders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastName]];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"To": responderFullName};

    //Check to see if we can make an outgoing call and attempt a connection if so
    NSNumber* hasOutgoing = [self.phone.capabilities objectForKey:TCDeviceCapabilityOutgoingKey];

    if ( [hasOutgoing boolValue] == YES ){
        //Disconnect if we've already got a connection in progress
        if(self.connection){
            [self.connection disconnect];
        }

        self.connection = [self.phone connect:params delegate:self];
        [self closeNoddersView:nil];
    }


}
- (void)connectionDidConnect:(TCConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Twilio connectionDidConnect");

    NSError *errorAudio;
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&errorAudio];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:nil];


    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    isSpeaker = success;
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@" error Audio %@", [errorAudio debugDescription]);
    }
}

-(void)connection:(TCConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    //Connection failed to responder failed
    NSLog(@" %@", [error  debugDescription]);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription]
                                                    message:@"We can't reach your responder"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [self.connection disconnect];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using right now to make 1-1 calls and I will see if I can suggest how you could update to make conference calls.

Comment: @philnash done and thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks @Bryan D, sorry to be a pain, could you share the TwiML you are using to set up the call, that's of more use in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @philnash now i'm the one who's sorry, i'm pretty new with twilio so could u be more precise ? Do u need the server side code (we follow the python quickstart) , do u need the "url" ?

Comment: Ah, ok, you've used the Python quickstart, that should be enough for me to go on! Answer coming up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As we worked out in the comments, you are using the iOS Client Quickstart that has a Python server. If you've followed the quickstart the whole way through you will know that when you send a `To` parameter that is a phone number then your application will call that number and when you send the `To` parameter that is a string starting with "client:" then your application will call through to another Client based application. This is all controlled on the server [by these lines](https://github.com/twilio/mobile-quickstart/blob/master/server.py#L52-L60).

What is happening is that when you dial out from the application, Twilio calls your Python server with the parameters you set to find out what to do next. The server returns TwiML, a subset of XML, with the instructions. Currently it returns various forms of [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), using either [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) to dial onto another Client or just inputting a number, which dials out to the phone network.

What we want is to dial into a conference call instead.

We can extend the Python server to do this. You will need to update your Python server with the following:

```
@app.route('/call', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def call():
  resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
  from_value = request.values.get('From')
  to = request.values.get('To')
  if not (from_value and to):
    return str(resp.say("Invalid request"))
  from_client = from_value.startswith('client')
  caller_id = os.environ.get("CALLER_ID", CALLER_ID)
  if not from_client:
    # PSTN -> client
    resp.dial(callerId=from_value).client(CLIENT)
  elif to.startswith("client:"):
    # client -> client
    resp.dial(callerId=from_value).client(to[7:])
  elif to.startswith("conference:"):
    # client -> conference
    resp.dial(callerId=from_value).conference(to[11:])
  else:
    # client -> PSTN
    resp.dial(to, callerId=caller_id)
  return str(resp)
```

I've added the following lines:

```
  elif to.startswith("conference:"):
    # client -> conference
    resp.dial(callerId=from_value).conference(to[11:])
```

This allows you to specify a `To` parameter that looks like "conference:CONF_NAME". If the server receives this, it will return TwiML that looks like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>CONF_NAME</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Which will drop the caller into a conference with the name CONF_NAME. Other callers can dial into the same conference by supplying the same name.

This is an extension to the quickstart, but hopefully you can see how you'd use this to create your conference.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: finally I set up the modification on the server and it's seems work perfectly, we can join a conference via our python code, now we are a little sticky because there's no guide/tuto about the moderation part. Do you prefere than I create a new question or can I ask your help here about the moderation part (mute, exclusion, get conference name etc)

Comment: Check out this tutorial on moderating conferences: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/conference-broadcast/java/spark. Hopefully that is a help, if not, it's best to open up a new question and one of us on the team will find it.

Comment: Great to hear that your app is working though! Would you mind accepting my answer so that other people can see that it helped? Thanks!